# delete() from Datasource does not trigger immediately after find()

Tags: cakephp, amazon-sqs

I have a custom Data Source, let's call it `SQSDatasource`. It's working fine, generally, for `find()`, `save()`, and even `delete()`.

```
class SQSDatasource extends DataSource {
    public function delete(Model $Model, $conditions = null) {

        // Deliberate break point to ensure that this function is being called
        print_r($conditions);
        exit();

        // I have my proper delete logic here, which works fine usually
    }
}
```

A Model, say `Job` that uses the `SQSDatasource`. There is no extraordinary logic in `Job`.

I am encountering a strange anomaly, however.

```
class TestShell extends AppShell {
    public $uses = array('Job');

    public function main() {
        // This works fine.
        $job = $this->Job->find('first');

        // The break point never gets called
        $this->Job->delete('TEST!');

        // This gets called
        $this->out('This gets called.');
    }
}
```

However, if I remove `$this->Job->find()` before calling `$this->Job->delete()`, it works perfectly fine. `delete()` would get called.

Anyone has any clue on this anomaly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to find out where the problem lies. My datasource code is actually complete with full implementation of `read()`, `create()`, etc. And all the standard CakePHP CRUD functions work fine with my datasource.

The problem I had is mainly due to these reasons:

1. `delete()` in CakePHP actually does a `find('count')` internally before allowing the delete, which I was not expecting
2. The behavior of [amazon-sqs](/questions/tagged/amazon-sqs). When a message is *in-flight*, it is temporarily *invisible*.
3. Also, for [amazon-sqs](/questions/tagged/amazon-sqs), you cannot delete a message without first querying it (as delete is done not via message ID, but via message handler). And once you start querying it, it becomes temporarily invisible, which results to CakePHP thinking that the delete is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have any of the code for doing finds, eg a read() function defined in your datasource. I suspect that with the find there it is failing and hence not doing the delete.

Once you remove the find there are no more errors and the delete works fine.

Check out the docs for [datasources](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/datasources.html) and make sure you have debug enabled. Possibly check the logs for any errors that are not being displayed.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. I have roughly found out where the problem lies, it's partly due to 2 reasons: i) the Amazon SQS inconsistencies; ii) I never expect datasource to do a find('count') first before deleting.

Comment: Just for the record, the datasource is actually fully implemented with `read()`, etc. I've added an explanation to this question below. Thanks.